# Can I rely on fetch to cache any resources in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, in page 1, we fetch a css file in javascript (assuming `mystyle.css` is not loaded before):

```js
fetch('/mystyle.css');
```

When the user later visits page 2, which contains this css resource:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Will `mystyle.css` gets fetched from cache? Can I rely on this behavior?

Comment: You can easily test this by checking the Network browser tool. My guess is "yes" but if it mattered to me I would definitely test it.

Comment: Assuming `mystyle.css` has the appropriate caching headers, yes.

Comment: When testing this with dev tools, make sure to turn off the setting "Disable HTTP Cache (when devtools are open)"